# Permalink something from a random array

Tags: javascript

This is semi-related to an earlier question I asked, relating to a site that plays music and sounds randomly, while working on this basic script I thought it would be useful to add the option to permalink what's currently playing in the user's browser. Is it in anyway possible within javascript itself?

here's a sample of what my actual code looks like:

```
theMusic[0] = '<audio controls autoplay onended="javascript:window.location.reload();"><source src= "1.ogg"></audio>';
theMusic[1] = '<audio controls autoplay onended="javascript:window.location.reload();"><source src= "2.ogg"></audio>';
theMusic[2] = '<audio controls autoplay onended="javascript:window.location.reload();"><source src= "3.ogg"></audio>';

var i = Math.floor(3*Math.random())
```

Comment: Sure, you can get the index from the URL and use that one instead of generating a random one. Do you have a *specific* question about this? Note that `javascript:` inside the attribute does not have any meaning and you can (and should) omit it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, I'm really new to this so how would I go about achieving that. I was more thinking among the lines of giving the user a link below the audio that gives them a direct link to the track currently playing.

Comment: You can do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the page, why not clear the `audio` element's **html** and have a function that generates a random number between **0** and **array.length** and use that number for the index value.  With that in mind, you can populate the elements html with the `<video>` and `<source>`.  This way, it can work similar as a playlist would.

It will look [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/2eXue/1/)  but you would still have to test across other browsers

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea! Thanks! I wish i could upvote that right now, haha